# Absolute Magnitude and Absolute Bolometric Magnitude

Tags: star, magnitude

What is the difference between Absolute Magnitude and Absolute Bolometric Magnitude, is it a case of multiply one by a constant to get the other?  Can you give an example for a star, say Vega?

Comment: Sorry, no homework.

Comment: Homework is accepted if you 1. self-identify as homework. 2. Clearly describe what research you have done already. 3. Clearly identify a specific problem

Comment: Not homework, I had another question open where Bolometric Magnitude was mentioned by James that I decided to not ask there but ask in a different question.

Answer (score 1):

From the page titled, "Absolute Magnitude" and with the disclaimer on that page "not about the magazine,"  [emphasis mine to aid in finding the info]

> Absolute magnitude is the measure of intrinsic brightness of a
>   celestial object. It is the hypothetical apparent magnitude of an
>   object at a standard distance of exactly 10 parsecs (32.6 light years)
>   from the observer, assuming no astronomical extinction of starlight.
>   This places the objects on a common basis and allows the true energy
>   output of astronomical objects to be compared without the distortion
>   introduced by distance. As with all astronomical magnitudes, the
>   absolute magnitude can be specified for different wavelength
>   intervals; for stars the most commonly quoted absolute magnitude is
>   the absolute visual magnitude, which uses only the visual (V) band of
>   the spectrum (UBV system). Also commonly used is the **absolute
>   bolometric magnitude**, which is the total luminosity expressed in
>   magnitude units that takes into account energy radiated at all
>   wavelengths, whether visible or not.

So in short, AbsMag is Visual Luminosity and AbsBol is Total Luminosity, Visual and Otherwise. (from comment by MiscellaneousUser)

Comment: So in short, AbsMag is Visual Luminosity and AbsBol is Total Luminosity, Visual and Otherwise.